# How to use fancy box in html and make it display in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am creating my own Github page and want to add a fancy box for my short bio. 
This is the code I have written for it:

```
<li>
  <a id="fbox" class="fancybox" href="#short-bio">Short Bio</a>
  <div id="short-bio" style="display:none;">
    <h3>Anmol Panda</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
</li>
```

The box displays 'on click' when I open the file locally using Google Chrome but it does not show up on the actual Github page. It also does not show up in Firefox. Can someone guide me what is going wrong and how I may correctly use it?

Sorry, I forgot to add the javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                    'width'        : '100%',
                    'height'       : '80%',
                    'autoScale'    : true,
                    'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
                    'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            });
    });
    </script>
```

Also, this is the website: https://anmol-007.github.io/
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. That html  with no script or css will do nothing special by itself

Comment: Please provide css and also what is the error showing in the console? If there is no error in the console it probably is a css typo. Please edit your post and provide css for the question

Comment: I have added the code here. And this is the real website: https://anmol-007.github.io/ . The code works fine on my system but not on the main site.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  openEffect : 'none',
  closeEffect : 'none'
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<a id="fbox" class="fancybox" href="#short-bio">Short Bio</a>
  <div id="short-bio" style="display:none;">
    <h3>Anmol Panda</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
```